# ScalaTest display original Failure stacktrace

Tags: scala, scalatest

How can display the original stacktrace for a Try Failure as part of the test output?

When I do the following:

```
 result.success.value should equal blah
```

And the result is a Failure I get

```
The Try on which success was invoked was not a Success.
```

Or, if I do this first:

```
result should be a 'success
```

It's a little more informative, because I can see the exception:

```
Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date) was not a success
```

But the stack trace shows where it failed in the test, not the original stack trace of the Failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some error-causing code is wrapped into Try, it means that exception is handled somewhere inside calculation, and it's cause and message will not be printed somewhere until explicitly requested. In order to see original cause, you can access failure object directly ([docs](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.TryValues)), or handle failure manually:

```
val (ok, message) = result match {
  case Success(v) => (true, "")
  case Failure(ex) =>
    (false, ex.getMessage + "\n" + ex.getStackTrace.mkString("\n"))
}

assert(ok, message)
```

[This link](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-convert-stack-trace-exception-string-print-logger-logging-log4j-slf4j) also looks helpful.

If you want original stack trace to be printed - use `result.get`, but check not for `'success` but inner type/value:

```
result.get should equal blah
```

Comment: I understand this, but would like ScalaTest to do this for me.